# Travis CI no se ejecuta al realizar un pull request en GitHub

Tags: github, travis-ci

Tengo el fichero travis.yml configurado de la siguiente manera:

```
 dist: trusty 
 language: java 
 jdk: oraclejdk8
 services:
   - mysql before_install:
   - mysql -e 'CREATE DATABASE petclinic;' 
 script: mvn test -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=mysql-travis
 
 addons:   
 sonarcloud:
 organization: ""
     token:   
         secure: "" 
 script:
    - mvn clean verify sonar:sonar -Pcoverage -Dsonar.projectKey = name
```

Pero no se me ejecuta. Sin embargo, si elimino la parte de addons hacia abajo sí se ejecuta. Aclaro que donde van las comillas y `name` van las correspondientes variables y tokens. No sé si el problema es por el esquema de estructura que sigo, la idea es incluir SonarCloud al analizar junto con Travis CI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escribo esto por si alguien tiene el mismo problema y no sabe cómo solucionarlo. El problema se ha resuelto eliminando la primera etiqueta de `script` y añadiendo el comando a la etiqueta de `script` final.